# linux add string to beginning of specific lines

Tags: linux, sed

I have a tab-delimited text file,starting with some lines that start with '#'.

```
#line1
#line2
#line3
1    a
1    b
```

Now for every line that doesn't start with '#', I want to add a string 'text'.

```
#line1
#line2
#line3
text1    a
text2    b
```

How can I do this? I thought of working with sed

```
sed "s/^[^#]/text/g" infile > outfile
```

But then the output for the first column on every line is just 'text' and not 'text1' or 'text2'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture and then reference the character matched by `[^#]`:

```
sed 's/^[^#]/text&/' infile > outfile
```